# Passing parameters to MSBuild tasks in Visual Studio 2010 (2012?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am trying to figure out how to specify values to MSBuild Tasks from within Visual Studio 2010.

For instance, I have a build task called "BuildMergeModule" defined, and this build task takes an Input property, it defines, called "SourceContent" where I can pass it a string with semicolon separated file/path specifications. The task then uses that to generate a Merge Module from this SourceContent specification for each target merge module in the project.

I can add the merge module files to the project and then assign it the Build Action of my "BuildMergeModule" task.

So, is it possible in VS 2010 (or VS 2012 if not VS 2010) to define the property so it shows up in the properties dialog on when that properties of each project merge module target is selected?

I can set the properties if I modify the MSBuild file directly. But, is there a way to get the Visual Studio design environment to present that property of a selected Task that is a build action?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the properties required in the property pages of C++ projects. For C# (or other types of projects) you will need to create a VSIX property page to expose your task input properties.

I won't describe how to create the VSIX property page, as I've minimal experience with those.

To create the property  page in a C++ project, open the 'Property Manager' from the View menu. You will see your projects in this window, and the various permutations of Platform|Configuration for each.

Right-click on the project you wish to create settings for and choose 'Add new property sheet...'. In the 'Add New Item' dialog that appears, name and place the property sheet file where you wish. Note that you can also add the new property sheet to a specific Platform/Configuration only if you like.

After the new property sheet is created, you will see it under the various Platform/Configuration sections in the Property Manager. Double-click on the property sheet to open its settings.

Click on 'User Macros' and add new macros with the settings you want to send to your task. For example, set a new macro called 'SourceContent' and set its value to the semi-colon delimited list of files you wish to construct your MergeModules with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but FYI, unless otherwise specified, you can assume that developers are not using C++.